# How to stop the baffle.js activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

How to stop the baffle.js activated?

here the code I wrote.
I cant stop the text acting while the div.baffle show..

http://codepen.io/QLCee/pen/mOXjWr

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
$('.baffle').each( function(i){

    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

     if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
(function () {
var Baffle;
Baffle = function () {
    function Baffle() {
        var $baffle, b;
        $baffle = $('.baffle');
        b = baffle('.baffle', {
            characters: '+-\u2022~\u2591\u2588\u2593 \u2593\u2592\u2591!=*',
            speed: 100
        });
        $baffle.addClass('is-started');
        b.start();
        b.reveal(2000);
    }
    return Baffle;
}();
$(function () {
    return new Baffle();
});
}.call(this));
    }

}); 

});
```

Comment: Would you say that it... baffles you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself is fine, just change the event from scroll to `click` and you'll see it works.
Your problem here is that the scroll event is fired multiple times, so it runs your function a bunch of times, and stops it 2000ms after the first call.
So, you need to throttle the event, something like below :

```js
var inProgress = false
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!inProgress) {
    inProgress = true;
    $('.baffle').each(function(i) {
      (function() {
        var Baffle;
        Baffle = function() {
          function Baffle() {
            var $baffle, b;
            $baffle = $('.baffle');
            b = baffle('.baffle', {
              characters: '+-\u2022~\u2591\u2588\u2593 \u2593\u2592\u2591!=*',
              speed: 100
            });
            $baffle.addClass('is-started');
            b.start();
            b.reveal(2000);
            setTimeout(()=>inProgress = false,2500)
          }
          return Baffle;
        }();
        $(function() {
          return new Baffle();
        });
      }.call(this));
    });
  } else {
    console.log('throttled');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: 'red';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/88019/baffle.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="contain">
  <div class="baffle">Hello Worldddd</div>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! is that possible just that the word actived for one time?

Comment: remove the setTimeout and it'll be a one-time thing